# Client Cookies not Sent to Django

Tags: python, django, cookies

I am having a weird problem with Django.  I set certain cookies on the client, but those cookies do not appear in the Django request.

The cookies properly appear in the client as follows:

```
"class_year_only=yes; email_status=yes; exit_status=yes; class_year_only_status=yes; nmstat=1448946715685; __utma=96992031.1943662208.1449612961.1449621554.1449704668.3; __utmz=96992031.1449612961.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); csrftoken=Oe2A6Qn7pwUshDEFAhyNa4dtGRajVe4S"
```

However, the Django request only shows the following cookies:

```
"{'csrftoken': Oe2A6Qn7pwUshDEFAhyNa4dtGRajVe4S, '__utma':96992031.1943662208.1449612961.1449621554.1449704668.3, '__utmz':96992031.1449612961.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none), 'nmstat':1448946715685}"
```

Why aren't the other cookies being sent?

Comment: Could the `secure` or `httponly` flags interfere? How are you running Django, with the development server?

Comment: Yeah, with the development server.

Comment: Are you using the ip address or `localhost` in your browser? Some browser handle cookies for `127.0.0.1` differently, so you should use `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I needed to set path to /.  The path in the client side cookie, used a subdomain which was the cause of the problem.  Not sure why, as the subdomain was correct.